# Which punctured Riemann surface are the complex structures of complete minimal surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemann-surfaces, minimal-surfaces

**Question**: Let $\Sigma$ be a punctured Riemann surface(i.e. a closed Riemann surface with several points removed). Is there always a complete conformal minimal immersion $X: \Sigma \to \mathbb{R}^3$?

When $\Sigma$ is a bordered surface, I can find many references. Can anyone give me some reference when $\Sigma$ is a punctured Riemann surface?

Answer (score 7):

It is proven in Pirola, Algebraic curves and non rigid minimal surfaces in the euclidean space, Pacific Journal of Math, Vol. 183, No. 2, 1998, that for every compact Riemann surface and every finite subset, there exist a complete immersed minimal surface on the complement of the finite subset. Actually, the surface have finite total curvature (and therefore meromorphic Weierstrass data), and come in non-trivial families.